# USing FTD2xx driver on Windows and Android

Tags: java, android, driver, ftdi

Does anyone know what the issue would be with my code below?

I'm trying to create an Android application that can access an external sensor and display the data that is being read from the device. I have managed to get back an array of bytes, but I'm not sure how this translates to the integer I was hoping to read.

I decided to start by creating a java application on Windows, to try and get a better understanding of the problem, before I create an Android application.

I feel like the project is set up correctly, I've imported the ftdichip.win32 and ftdichip.ftd2xx libraries, and I think that I have managed to find the device.

However, I am unable to read the values that I hope the sensor is collecting. I am not sure if it's something to do with unsigned bytes?

I have included my code below and any help that can be offered would be greatly appreciated.

```
    import jd2xx.JD2XX;
```

Above is the only necessary import (to my understanding?)

```
    JD2XX jd = new JD2XX();

    //list by Serial Number
    Object[] devs = jd.listDevicesBySerialNumber();
    for (int i = 0; i < devs.length; ++i) {
        System.out.println(devs[i]);
    }

    //List by Description
    devs = jd.listDevicesByDescription();
    for (int i = 0; i < devs.length; ++i) {
        System.out.println(devs[i]);
    }

    //List by location
    devs = jd.listDevicesByLocation();
    for (int i = 0; i < devs.length; ++i) {
        System.out.println(
                Integer.toHexString((Integer) devs[i]));
    }

    //open device
    jd.open(0);

    //configure the device
    jd.setBaudRate(38400);
    jd.setDataCharacteristics(
            8, JD2XX.STOP_BITS_1, JD2XX.PARITY_NONE);
    jd.setTimeouts(100, 100); //Set the time in ms between reads and writes (i think)
    jd.setFlowControl(JD2XX.FLOW_NONE, 0, 0);
    jd.setTimeouts(1000, 1000);

    while (true) {
    //try this 
    String msg = "So i can send it a message";
    int ret = jd.write(msg.getBytes())
    System.out.println(ret + "bytes sent.");

    //read 
    int test = jd.read()
    System.out.println("This is what is returned: " + test);
    }
```

If anyone could explain the reason why I am not getting any values from the device you would be an absolute life saver.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

You should check the queue first:

```
int status = ftDev.getQueueStatus();
byte[] data = new byte[(int) status]; 
long lngBytesReturned = ftDev.read(data,data.length);
```

I used the android d2xx library with the D2xxManager
 from the FTDI website.

Comment: Thank you. Can you tell me about the sensor that you have attached to your usb? Is it externally powered?

Comment: I connected a FTDI USB-Serial adapter to the OBDII port, and yes its powered by the car battery (+12V), what data are you reading? If you expect unsigned bytes and the read method uses java byte implementation, you can just add 256 in case of a negative number, its the same bit representation, after 127 you get -128(unsigned 128),-127...-1 (unsigned 255).

Comment: I am trying to read data from [this](http://www.dynament.com/infrared-sensor-data/tds0037.pdf) sensor, which is unpowered. Sorry for the barrage of questions, but do you send a write to the device before you call the read method? Also, are you working with values such as "0x13", it is my first encounter with them and any recommended reading on the subject would be appreciated.

Comment: I dont know the specs on your adapter or have worked before with that sensor, but is worth checking this section 
"Digital interface
The digital communication pins “RX” and “TX” operate at a 2.8V logic level. When interfacing to
external circuitry that uses a higher voltage level it is necessary to limit the current that can flow.
The external voltage level should be 5V maximum and a 3K3 resistor should be used in series with
each communication pin. "

The obd-like protocol that I'm using is a request-reply one, I send a Hex request (like 0x13) converted to the Integer representation.

Comment: Then I check the Queue and read 2 bytes, the first one is the sent request, second byte is the reply (integer value).

Comment: Thank you, I will check this out. That really really useful information, I'll get back to you tomorrow as to whether or not it solves my troubles :)